Spark reading CSV with bad records
I am trying to read a csv file in spark using a pre-defined schema. For which I use:
df = (spark.read.format("csv")
        .schema(schema)
        .option("sep", ";")
        .load(
            file_path,
            header=True,
            encoding="utf-8"))

In this case the data gets loaded without any issues.
Now when I provide a bad records path, I get no records:
df = (
        spark.read.format("csv")
        .schema(schema)
        .option("sep", ";")
        .option(
            "badRecordsPath",
            bad_records_path,
        )
        .load(
            file_path,
            header=True,
            encoding="utf-8",
        ))

All the records are dumped into the bad records path with the error. MALFORMED_CSV_RECORD (SQLSTATE: KD000) even though the schema used is exactly the same. Why would I be getting this error?

Could you share a small sample of what the CSV looks like?

So I looked into the data in detail and it seems that each line in the csv file end with the delimeter ":" and that seems to be causing the issue. Is there a way to read such files in spark

df = sqlContext.read 
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") 
.option("header", "true") 
.option("delimiter", ";") 
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") 
.option("charset", "UTF-8") 
.schema(schema) 
.load(final_file_path)
df.display()

The solution that worked for me was adding an additional random StructField in the schema at the end(since order of fields matter for csv). I used StringType but any type should work. Spark will try to parse an additional column after the last delimeter at the end of the line and populate that column with nulls. The original data would be validated by the schema provided and bad records will be moved to quarantine. After reading the data, extra column can be dropped.
Edit: adding an example
Suppose we have a csv file with the following data:
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;
3088548;"1166263";"something";"something";;

In the above file we have 5 columns with a delimeter at the end. If we define our schema with just 5 columns and try to read the file we won't get any results and all records will be dumped in badRecords with MALFORMED error:

But if we define our schema with one extra random column at the end then we would be able to read the file while validating the schema:

After reading we can drop the extra column(col6).

You can use the .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") to skip bad rows.
df = sqlContext.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", ";") \
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
    .option("charset", "UTF-8") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .load(final_file_path)
df.display()

Results:
name    age job
John    30  Developer
Jane    25  Designer

The solution code skips lines in the CSV file that have an incorrect number of delimiters or do not match the specified schema.
This prevents these lines from causing errors later in the code by filtering them out during the initial data reading and parsing process.

Actually I want those records since there is an extra delimeter on each line. The solution that finally worked for me was to add one extra field in the schema at the end which was being read as null and then drop it after read. So the schema is validated and genuine bad records are moved to quarantine.
